# Calculate distance after rotation?

Tags: geometry, 3d, rotations

I'll start off by saying that I suck at math.

I'm trying to calculate the distance between a circle and the center of the screen after rotating an image that contains that circle by $45^\circ$ in $3D$,

(The $y$ distance of the object changes as the image rotates)

[image]

I hope I made myself clear, thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried something? Just try to describe the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose that the projection point is on the line perpendicular to the middle of the screen (at a distance $z$) then the vertical tangent at the view point will change from $\displaystyle\frac yz$ to $\displaystyle\frac {y\,\cos(\alpha)}{z+y\,\sin(\alpha)}$ after a vertical rotation of angle $\alpha$.

This implies that $\,y\,$ will become $\ \displaystyle h(\alpha):=\frac {y\,z\,\cos(\alpha)}{z+y\,\sin(\alpha)}$.

For $\,\alpha=\frac{\pi}4\,$ you should get : $$y':=h\left(\frac{\pi}4\right)=\frac {y\,z}{y+\sqrt{2}z}$$

---

After rotation of $(oy)$ of an angle $\alpha$ we get following picture (from the side) :

[image: alpha rotation]

Now observe the triangle obtained and notice that :
$$\frac{y\,\cos(\alpha)}{z+y\,\sin(\alpha)}=\frac{y'}z$$

Comment: Wow, I must say that I've never been as confused before. lol I suppose I'll need someone to simplify this answer for me D:

Comment: I'll add a drawing in my answer to clarify a little...

Comment: That'll be great! :D

Comment: @Don: I updated my answer. Is this clearer?

Comment: @RaymondManzoni It is a lot clearer, what I am a bit confused about is how to implement this in code ( i needed this for a game I'm programming ) - even my Z is at 0 at the moment, does it mean I'll have to determine what Z is first?

Comment: @Don: I think that in your case $z$ will simply be the constant side of one of your four (equal) squares : it is the distance from your eye to the screen ($z$ can't be zero!). This constant $z$ should already appear in your other projections formula.

Comment: Alright, well I'll try to figure this out then :) by the way, what if the circle on the image would move around it, how would I be able to know where the image needs to move to on the screen so that the circle will be on the center of the screen, and always at the same size?

Comment: @RaymondManzoni, I misread it.

Comment: No problem @Loki !

Comment: @Don, it seems like you want the distance on the screen to the center of the circle, not to the nearest point on the circle as you depict. After projecting the center onto the screen, you can shift the image by that amount to center it, or shift the screen by that amount the other way.

Comment: @LokiClock I thought so, but by the question I asked , I'll only be able to know how much to shift the image on the screen on the y axis, which means that if the circle goes too far, it'll still be centered, but too small to see. so I will probably need to also figure out how much to shift the image on the Z axis, or am I wrong? I'm so confused with this 3d thing lol

Comment: If you move to where the focus point is the origin, you can just scale the whole plane, which will move it towards the screen while maintaining the apparent sizes of objects. If you center the screen on the apparent center of the circle, move to the screen's origin, and shrink the screen, the circle will appear to grow without moving.

Comment: @Don: (sorry for the delay... that could help you to know what you want :-)). As pointed by Loki it could be better to track the center of the circle (ellipse after projection). But in 3D you may track it in different ways : move the eye on the line perpendicular to the screen on the center of the circle, zoom part of the screen, consider $z$ very large (so that the 3D-projection becomes a mere perpendicular/isometric projection). Note that the aspect of the ellipse may be different with the different methods. The size of the ellipse will be more or less proportional to $\frac 1z$.

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Hey, I see. although my math level is really low so I'm still finding it hard to actually create what you showed here in code hehe, I suppose I'll need to take a little read and learn some trigonometry before trying again, It'd be great if I could actually chat with you just to clear a few issues I have with understanding your answer ;x but I don't  want to bother you too much, you helped me quite a lot already lol, so yeah thank you very much!

Comment: @Don: we may start a chat in the generic chatroom ['Mathematics'](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics) now if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of a more naiive way of doing this calculation that I hope illustrates how images are really taken of things, and how that means you have to manipulate the camera to manipulate the image.

In step 1, the perspective point F and either of the other points (the centers of the planes) can be chosen arbitrarily.

Something to think about: images in our vision are really upside-down, but our brains correct them.

[image: The projection of a point onto a plane]